# Ruby on Rails - filtered @ variable persisted between logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Firstly here is my ruby and rails version with a couple of the important gem versions.

- Ruby 1.9.3-p125
- Rails 3.2.2
- Devise 2.0.4
- CanCan 1.6.7

I used the template from Daniel Kehoe to get the project up and running quickly.

```
$ rails new myapp -m https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails3-application-templates/master/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber-template.rb -T
```

**My problem:**

I have an administration section for creating new users and two roles with this ability. I have a requirement, admin users should not be able to create superadmin users.

When an admin logs in and clicks on the new user button the roles list is filtered to remove the superadmin option, if I logout of the admin role and login as a superadmin then create a user I have the filtered list from the admin. If I refresh 5-6 times I get the correctly filtered list.

User model

```
# /app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES = { 
    superadmin: 'superadmin', 
    admin:      'admin'
  }

  def role?(role)
    self.role == role.to_s
  end
end
```

User controller

```
# /app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
module Admin
  class UsersController < BaseController
    load_and_authorize_resource

    def new
      @user = User.new
      @roles = User::ROLES

      if current_user.role? :admin
        @roles.delete :superadmin
      end
    end
  end
end
```

View

```
# /app/views/admin/users/_form.html.haml
= form_for [:admin, @user], html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  ...
  .control-group
    = f.label :role, class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.select :role, @roles, selected: :admin
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction as to why the @roles is retaining its value between login/logouts for users with different roles but then being cleared that would be really helpful thanks, I've been stumped on this for over an hour as has a few others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line `@roles = User::ROLES` is getting a **reference** to User::ROLES instead of a copy. So, when you call `@roles.delete :superadmin`, you're modifying User::ROLES, too.

I'm guessing after 5-6 requests, your request is served by a different process whose global copy has not (yet) been modified.

To solve the provlem, change `@roles = User::ROLES` to `@roles = User::ROLES.dup`

Or, change `@roles.delete :superadmin` to `@roles = @roles.except(:superadmin)`

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I had a feeling this was the problem but wasn't quite sure how to fix it. I tried .to_hash etc and nothing worked :)